# Split a P element into several P elements based on BR elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to split a single P element that contains several SPAN's and BR's into separate P elements by BR elements.

Here is the sample input xml structure:

```
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="BYLINE">by john doe</SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">
        <BR/>
     </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="EMAIL">john.doe@email.com</SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">
        <BR/>
     </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="BOLD">This sentence is bold. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="ITALIC">This sentence is in italics. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        <BR/>
     </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="BOLD">BOLD SUBTITLE HERE</SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">
        <BR/>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="ITALIC">
        <BR/>ITALIC SUB-TITLE</SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">
        <BR/>Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.<BR/>
     </SPAN>
  </P>
```

And the output xml that I would like to see is:

```
  <P>
    <SPAN CLASS="BYLINE">by john doe</SPAN>
  </P>
  <P>
    <SPAN CLASS="EMAIL">john.doe@email.com</SPAN>
  </P>
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="BOLD">This sentence is bold. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="ITALIC">This sentence is in italics. </SPAN>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</SPAN>
  </P>
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="BOLD">BOLD SUBTITLE HERE</SPAN>
  </P>
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</SPAN>
  </P>
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="ITALIC">ITALIC SUB-TITLE</SPAN>     
  </P>
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</SPAN>
  </P>
  <P>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT"></SPAN>
  </P>
```

Is this possible?
I was trying to use xsl:key and grouping but can't make it work.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you have tried so far? Having said that, if you are using xslt 2.0, then this could be a job for `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-ending-with`. Thanks!

Comment: Why does the ultimate `BR` result in an empty `<P>
     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT"></SPAN>
  </P>  ` while other `     <SPAN CLASS="TEXT">
        <BR/>
     </SPAN>` don't show up in the output?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks for checking out my post. it is because the last <SPAN CLASS="TEXT"> has a <BR/> element at the end of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, it looks like you could use `xsl:for-each-group` combined with `group-ending-with`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="SPAN" group-ending-with="*[BR]">
```

You would then use the `current-group()` function to get all the `SPAN` elements you want grouped in a `P`

```
<P>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
</P>
```

You would also need templates to stop `BR` tags, and `SPAN` tags containing only `BR` tags, being output.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="P">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="SPAN" group-ending-with="*[BR]">
            <P>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </P>           
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[BR][not(normalize-space())]" />

    <xsl:template match="BR" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This doesn't quite give you the output you need, because `<SPAN CLASS="BOLD">BOLD SUBTITLE HERE</SPAN>` combines with the following span, rather than being in it's own `P` tag, but I couldn't work out why the logic for that was different.

See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html for more interesting ways to use `xsl:for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Hi @tim-c, thanks for your checking out my post and posting your suggestion. i will try this out and give you an update.

Comment: hi @TimC, thanks for your suggestion. it works for majority of the cases. the only part where it does not work is where the BR element is somewhere in the middle, and not at the end of the SPAN.  Also, thanks for the link you sent about grouping with XSLT.

Comment: in the end, the other party producing the source xml has agreed to change the format of the xml to a simpler one which involves just P elements.